# dataGridView select a row's cell and get first cell's value C#

Tags: c#, datagridview, visual-studio-2019

I have a dataGridView and I need to get the first cell's value, by clicking on any cell of it's row

for example:
in row num.2, I might click on cell[0]/ cell[1]/ cell[2] or any other cell
what I need is to get cell[0]'s value of the row, no matter which one of it's cells I click on

the peace of code I'm using, only allows me to get the value, only by clicking on the 0th cell itself, not when another cell of it's row is clicked on:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            id = (int)dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value;
        }
```

any help would be appreciated♥

Comment: I am not following what you are asking… the grids `CellClick` event will fire when ANY cell is clicked. I am not sure what you mean by… _”...only allows me to get the desired value, only by clicking on the 0th cell itself:”_ … ? …

Comment: yes, the event is fired if any cell is clicked, but i want a specific cell's value, and that's why i've given it the index of 0th cell
do you know how to tell it to get the value of one specific cell, when any cell is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

First of all please be aware that the CellClick event might not be what you want.

From MS documentation:

> To determine when the cell contents are clicked, handle the CellContentClick event.

Have a closer look here: [Microsoft DataGridView documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellclick?view=windowsdesktop-6.0)

Nevertheless, it's hard to guess without having the code where you bind the event. But I would say the problem is somewhere in the code where you attach the event listener.